# jquery datatables search php [codeigniter] not working

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I am using jquery datables for showing some stocks. By default all stock are showing but when I type some text in search box nothing happens, I have also check console there is no error, Please help me. Here is some code:

**stock.js**

```
$('#view-stock').DataTable({
    serverSide:true,
    searchable:true,
    ajax:{
        url:base_url+"stock/get_stock",
    }..and so on
```

**stock_controller:**

```
public function get_stock(){
    $stock['data']=$this->Stock_model->get_stock();
    if(isset($_GET['search[value]'])){
        $stock['data']=$this->Stock_model->get_stock($_GET['search[value]']);
    }
    $stock=json_encode($stock);
    print_r($stock);
}
```

**stock model:**

```
public function get_stock($search=null){
            $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
            if($search!=null){
                $this->db->like('p_name', $search);
                $stock=$this->db->get('stockdetail');
            }else{
                $stock=$this->db->get('stockdetail');
            }
            if($stock){
                return $stock->result_array();
            }
            return false;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Check request response body in browser developer console what php return.

Comment: try change print_r to echo.

Comment: check out `ignited datatables`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:i hope it will help you.
 //js

```
 var dtable = $('#view-stock').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: false,
            searching: true,
            dom: 'lBfrtip',
            lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
            pageLength: 10,
            buttons: [
                'csv', 'print'
            ],
            ajax: {
                "url": base_url + "/stock/datatables",
                'method': 'POST',
                'data': function (d) {
                    d._token = $("input[name=_token]").val();
                }
            }
//controller


 function index() {
        $data = array();
        $data['view'] = 'view_page_name';
      $this->load->view('header', $data);
    }
     function datatables() {
            $data = array();
            $stock =$this->Stock_model->get_stock($this->input->post());
            parent::json_output(["draw" => intval($this->input->post('draw')), "recordsTotal" => $stock[1], "recordsFiltered" =>$stock[1], "data" => $stock[0]]);
            return;
        }
```

//model

```
function get_stock($requestArray) {

        if (isset($requestArray['keyword']) && $requestArray['keyword'] != '') {
            $this->db->where .= " AND (field_name_by_which_you_want_search LIKE '%" . $requestArray['keyword'] . "%')";
            $this->db->where .= " AND (field_name_by_which_you_want_search LIKE '%" . $requestArray['keyword'] . "%')";
        }
        $this->db->where($where);
        if ($this->input->post('length') != '-1') {
            $this->db->limit($this->input->post('length'), $this->input->post('start'));
        }
 $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
        $query = $result->get('stockdetail')->result_array();

        $count = $result->get('stockdetail')->num_rows();
        return [$query, $count];
    }
```

Comment: Yes it helped me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` is an array.  `'search'` is a key which contains another array so you've accessed the parameters incorrectly. Change this:

```
if(isset($_GET['search[value]'])){
    $stock['data']=$this->Stock_model->get_stock($_GET['search[value]']);
}
```

To:

```
if(isset($_GET['search']['value'])){
    $stock['data']=$this->Stock_model->get_stock($_GET['search']['value']);
}
```

Also, I'm not sure what your method returns but if you are doing server side processing you should make sure that it's a json in the proper format — which is roughly:

```
$json = json_encode(array(
    'data'              => $results,
    'draw'              => (int)$_GET['draw'],
    'recordsTotal'      => // total records in unfiltered result set,
    'recordsFiltered'   => // number of records returned
));
```

If your result set is empty you should still return results in this format and just send an empty array in the `data` key.  *Don't return `false`* — this will cause DataTables to throw an error since it's an invalid response.  Read up more on server-side processing in datatables here: https://datatables.net/manual/server-side